# Function which returns a new list with the first and last elements removed

Tags: function, haskell

I am very new to Haskell and am trying a simple exercise for practice.  I want to write a function that removes the first and last elements of a list.

I do not need to check if the length of the list.  I found in a book I have a way to remove the first element and a way to reverse the list, but I think this may be more complex than it has to be. I also know that complexity aside, what I have is wrong after the second line, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
midList :: [a] -> [a]
midList [a] = tail [a]
[a] = reverse [a]
[a] = tail [a]
[a] = reverse [a]
```

Comment: In Haskell, lists are immutable, so you can't change them (in case it was not clear). You can return a new list representing what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain to me what `[a] = reverse [a]` is supposed to do? To program in Haskell, you need to think more mathematically, in terms of functions (and composition and application of functions), not much in terms of "returning values different times and then putting them together".

Comment: Sorry, but I had to downvote this question because the problem you're describing is caused by the fact that you have not put enough effort in learning Haskell. Please, take it as an encouragement to put more effort next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compose your steps functionally. Your proposed code could be rewritten as:

```
midList :: [a] -> [a]
midList xs = reverse (tail (reverse (tail xs)))
```

Note that `tail` will crash your program if it is ever passed the empty list. You can, and should, avoid that by either 1) checking if the list has at least two elements, or 2) using `drop 1` instead of `tail`, which will simply return `[]` on the empty list.

If you try 2), you can keep your function type. For approach 1), instead, you can report the error to the caller using a `Maybe [a]` return type. More concretely:

```
midList :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
midList xs@(_:_:_) = Just (reverse (tail (reverse (tail xs))))
midList _          = Nothing
```

where the pattern `_:_:_` stands for a list which has at least two elements.

Alternatively, use both `init` and `tail`: the former removes the last element, the latter removes the first element.

```
midList :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
midList xs@(_:_:_) = Just (init (tail xs))
midList _          = Nothing
```

Be however quite careful here, since in general it is best to avoid partial functions like `init` and `tail`. As a general rule, one should never use them if a more basic approach does the job, e.g. using pattern matching.

Here, I would find the code above to be suboptimal. I'd prefer the following, coding my own "safe" version of `init` to remove the last element, if any, or report the error otherwise.

```
midList :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
midList (_:xs@(_:_)) = safeInit xs
midList _            = Nothing

safeInit :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safeInit [] = Nothing
safeInit (x:xs) = case safeInit xs of
   Nothing -> Just []
   Just ys -> Just (x:ys)
```

Comment: My advice is just to replace `init` and `tail` with saturating versions; see my answer.

Comment: @dfeuer Would that mean using `drop 1` as I suggest above as option 2), and some similar "dropLast" (to be coded)? There are many ways to solve this exercise. (And, BTW, I don't think this is a good beginner exercise -- asking to code a partial function rarely is, IMO).

Comment: That's certainly an option! `dropLast n xs = zipWith const xs (drop n xs)`.

Comment: If the students are beginning programmers, or even just starting with functional programming, then yes, I definitely agree with you. More experienced students can more reasonably be expected to find reasonable ways to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do is to make sure you understand the problem. In particular, what do you want to happen if the list has no elements, or just one? The easiest thing is probably to just return the empty list in that case. So let's do that. We can break up the problem into two pieces:

1. Remove the first element of a list
2. Remove the last element of a list

The Haskell prelude defines a couple functions we really don't want, so let's hide them:

```
import Prelude hiding (tail, init)
```

Now we can define better versions of those functions. `tail` will return all but the first element of a list and `init` will return all but the last element. Then we can write

```
chop :: [a] -> [a]
chop xs = init (tail xs)
```

`tail` is the easiest to write. I'll provide the skeleton and you can fill in the missing bits.

```
tail :: [a] -> [a]
tail [] = ????
tail (x : xs) = ????
```

`init` is only a little bit trickier. Note that one of the cases will be recursive.

```
init :: [a] -> [a]
init [] = ????
init [x] = ????
init (x : xs) = ????
```